# How to find bind event to any element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

Let,

```
<span onclick="foo()" onfocus="goo()">Have Event</span>
```

Here I give this just for example. Here with the `span` two events have bind.

Is there any ***javascript*** or ***jquery*** way to find out all events bind with any html element?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Sorry, but I always feel physical pain when I see a `href` attribute on a `span`.

Comment: @bazmegajapa sorry it was a mistake

Comment: Did you check my answer? is it working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't with DOM2-style event handlers (ones added with `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`), which pretty much means you don't want to be doing this as DOM2+ handlers are increasingly The Way It Shall Be Done<sup>(tm)</sup>.

The ones you've shown in your example are DOM0 event handlers, though, which you *can* check for: <s>You can loop through the properties on the element, looking at the ones starting with "on", and see whether they have a value:</s>

```
var element = document.getElementById("theSpan");
var name;
for (name in element) {
    if (name.substring(0, 2) === "on" && element[name]) {
        // It has a DOM0 handler for the event named by `name`
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Apparently, at least on Chrome, the `onXyz` properties are non-enumerable so they don't show up in `for..in` loops. And on Firefox, you only see the ones assigned programmatically, not via attributes.

So, you can test them explicitly:

```
if (element.onclick) {
    // It has a DOM0-style `click` handler
}
```

...but you'll have to have a list of the ones you want to know about.

Here's an example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/awocal)):

HTML:

```
<p id="thePara" onclick="foo()">This is the paragraph</p>
<script>
  // Some other bit of code setting a DOM0 handler programmatically
  document.getElementById("thePara").onmousedown = function() {
    display("<code>onmousedown</code> called for thePara");
  };
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Look up all handlers on thePara
  var element = document.getElementById("thePara");
  var name;
  var names = "onclick onmousedown onchange onmouseup".split(" ");
  var index;

  for (name in element) {
    if (name.substring(0, 2) === "on" && element[name]) {
      display("[loop check] thePara has handler for <code>" + name + "</code>");
    }
  }

  for (index = 0; index < names.length; ++index) {
    name = names[index];
    if (element[name]) {
      display("[explicit check] thePara has handler for <code>" + name + "</code>");
    }
  }
};

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

function foo() {
  display("<code>foo</code> called");
}
```

Note again, though, that you probably don't want to do this, as you'll miss DOM2+ handlers.

Also note that an event may be handled when you click an element even though that element doesn't have an event handler for the event — because the event can *bubble* to the parent, which looks at the `event.target`, sees the relevant child, and takes appropriate action. This is how *event delegation* works, and it too is increasingly The Way It Shall Be Done<sup>(tm)</sup>, so... :-)

Comment: I found your solution very helpful. but i have some other ambition. I want to make query on each element and find attach events to them.

Comment: @abdullah: You basically can't, as I've said. You can use the above combined with a global search to find out about DOM0 handlers, but you can't find out about DOM2+ handlers.

Comment: @abdullah: ?? I think that must have been a mistranslation.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, `.data('events')` stores all the bound events of the element.

> In jQuery 1.4.3 setting an element's
>   data object with .data(obj) extends
>   the data previously stored with that
>   element. jQuery itself uses the
>   .data() method to save information
>   under the names 'events' and 'handle',
>   and also reserves any data name
>   starting with an underscore ('_') for
>   internal use.

[jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

**This method only works though for events that are bound through jQuery.**

Comment: This will *only* relate to events hooked up via jQuery's `bind`, though, not the events in the example shown or other events hooked via `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to get all the events but we can get it by specifying it..
Here is the JQuery code to track elements and events for onclick, onfocus and onblur..

```
<div id="log"></div>
<script language="javascript">
$('*[onclick],*[onblur],*[onfocus]').each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('onclick'))
    $('#log').html($('#log').html()+'<br>'+this.tagName+' : onclick : '+$(this).attr('onclick'));
    if($(this).attr('onblur'))
    $('#log').html($('#log').html()+'<br>'+this.tagName+' : onblur : '+$(this).attr('onblur'));
    if($(this).attr('onfocus'))
    $('#log').html($('#log').html()+'<br>'+this.tagName+' : onfocus : '+$(this).attr('onfocus'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: my main objective is to make a query and find event that are bind to a element with the element type. I don't want to predefined any event array or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for curiosity, and you don't need this data processed further by any script you can use [visual event bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).

Comment: hi friend,curiosity makes someone to know something, so i wrote that. And after getting some knowledge everyone apply it to do something. so I am not an exception